# Wondering if there are other ways in addition to adding indicies to make following sql query more efficient

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT patientid.acct
FROM   patientid,
       doc_table
WHERE  patientid.acct = doc_table.acct
       AND patientType IN ( 'I', '1', 'T' )
       AND fid IN ( '023' )
       AND ( dischargedate IS NULL
              OR dischargedate = ''
              OR dischargedate < '19000101' )
       AND dbcreate_date > DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE());
```

We will be adding indicies for patientType, fid dischargedate and dbcreate_date.   But I wondering if the query itself could be written in a different way to make it more efficient.

Thank you,

Comment: (I rolled back to my edit as it fixes the somewhat distracting smart quotes in the original query.) What is the datatype of `dischargedate`? Why isn't it `date` or `datetime` datatype?

Answer (score 1):

Without more info it's hard to be prescriptive, but in general:

1 - Are you sure you need to `DISTINCT`?  That can be an expensive operation on larger data sets.  Run the query without it to see if the results differ.  If they do you may want to change the structure to eliminate duplicates.

2 - Put your **most restrictive** condition in your `WHERE` clause first, then in descending order of restriction.  For example, if your `patienttype` filter drops the results to 50%, but the `fid` filter drops it to 20%, use the `fid` filter first.

3 - for indexes, make sure your `JOIN` keys are indexed: `patientid.acct` and `doc_table.acct`  this will probably have the biggest impact on performance.

As a side not, use explicit `JOIN` syntax, it's much easier to read and maintain, especially on longer queries.  A revised version would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT patientid.acct
FROM   patientid 
INNER JOIN  doc_table
    ON patientid.acct = doc_table.acct
WHERE patientType IN ( 'I', '1', 'T' )
...
```

Comment: SQL Server does not use short circuit evaluation as implied by your point 2. It will rearrange the conditions automatically as it sees fit.

Comment: @Martin - There are circumstances where it matters, and I've had it improve performance on long-running queries.  Normally it's only if an `EXISTS` is involved, see: http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2010/04/looking-under-hood.html

Comment: I would only add the use of GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT as a last alternative.

Comment: @Dems - AFAIK SQL Server treats a single-field `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` the same.

Comment: @JNK - I can't see anything relevant in that link? Order of evaluation is guaranteed for `CASE` expressions and `COALESCE` gets expanded out to `CASE` but from a quick skim I don't see anything that claims the order that they are written in the query apart from that makes any difference whatsoever.

Comment: @MArtin - towards the middle, under the section `NOT EXISTS ==> LEFT (ANTI SEMI) JOIN`

Comment: @JNK - Sorry I missed that in my skim. Very interesting. Just reading it now. +1 That was a new one for me. Paul White's comment indicates that it would only apply to [anti] semi joins though.

Comment: @martin - it's a limited use case but I always try to get in the habit regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE EXISTS` instead of a `JOIN` and getting rid of the duplicates with `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should consider: Fix the values for the column `dischargedate` and select one value which says `null or '' or < '19000101'` so you can get rid of the `or`: a) it costs time and b) a database shouldn't be a mess.